# What is this part in the image?

Tags: integrated-circuit, dc-motor, feedback

I'm fiddling with a toy and I found this part. I think its purpose is give feedback to a microcontroller about the angle of the DC motors.

This is the part:

[image]

This is how it's placed with the motors:

[image]

This is where it goes on the main PCB:

[image]

I hope you know this part. I don't know how to search for it so that's why I'm here.

Comment: That one's an assembly but there are similar opto-sensors (shaped like the black covers) readily available.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_encoder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I hope you know this part. I dont know how to search for it so that's
> why im here. Any help would be appreciated.*

[image]

It's a slotted LED/photodiode (or phototransistor) detector and comes in various size and shapes and is made by several well-known manufacturers.

- [Omron Through Beam (Fork) Photoelectric Sensor](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/photoelectric-sensors/8074560/?cm_mmc=UK-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-CSS_UK_EN_Automation_%26_Control_Gear_Whoop-_-Photoelectric+Sensors_Whoop+(2)-_-8074560&matchtype=&pla-337077531107&gclid=CjwKCAjw6fCCBhBNEiwAem5SOwiEFnnq5oVAus0tbaCe-k44fKpyg-w7IaVDBOFuj-zpA8m8q9fcPxoCEcAQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)
- [ROHM, Through Hole Slotted Optical Switch](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/slotted-optical-switches/7003999/?cm_mmc=UK-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-PLA_UK_EN_Displays_%26_Optoelectronics_Whoop-_-Slotted+Optical+Switches_Whoop-_-7003999&matchtype=&pla-477185649511&gclid=CjwKCAjw6fCCBhBNEiwAem5SOxmpOWUhCTtJFG4S5nleotxlAAjxrbyNxE6CqFSlGGkTJeiFCpiachoCawYQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

To name but two.

Answer (score 1):

The combo photodiode-led allows the micro to detect motor movement. The LED shines through the slots in the wheel, illuminating the photodiode and sending an impulse to the microcontroller. The slotted wheel allows only information about the speed to be sensed, not an absolute position. A more complex arrangement, with patterned slots and possibly multiple detectors could be used to detect position/angle (see gray code for an implementation of this).